# Does total network traffic being higher than the bit rate of a device's ethernet controller affect the controller?

Tags: networking, ethernet, wireshark, bitrate

I am using a Wago 750 ethernet controller on a local network that is at its peak hitting ~38,000,000 bits / second as per Wireshark.  The Wago is becoming semi-unresponsive around the time of this peak, and I am trying to debug whether the network traffic could be a cause.  According to wireshark, the number of bits from packets that have a source or destination of the controller's ip address peaks at ~8000 bits /second.  According to the specs of the Wago 750 manual, the ethernet controller has a "baud rate" (their words) of 10 Mbit/s.  (The manual is here: https://www.wago.com/global/d/1256, the tech specs for the ethernet are on pg. 67, picture below for convenience.)

[Screenshot of Wago 750 manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpnXt.png)

My question, due to almost total ignorance about computer networking: do the packets that are on the network that are not being sent to or received by the ip address of a device still contribute to the device's total bit rate?

Sorry for the basic question, I am struggling to find the right terms to google.

Comment: This devices is only capable of a 10Mb/s Ethernet connection link, so in theory it is limited by the layer 2 link to 10,000,000 bps (reality is a little lower)... Your switch should be regulating traffic to the maximum link speed and only passing traffic on that port that is specific to that mac address, or has no specific destination like broadcast packets... And all packets sent to the device's interface "count", otherwise things like broadcast storms wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Are you running WireShark on the device with the Wago? WireShark works by telling the Ethernet port it is listening over to go into "promiscuous mode", which means it will actually read every packet it can over the network. Otherwise, ethernet devices normally only listen to the packets addressed to them, or multicast (sent to everyone). If you have a 2nd computer, you should be using that to do this test. If you were getting slowdowns before setting up WireShark, it is possible they are related to the ethernet device, but also possible they aren't, because WireShark itself may be a factor.

Comment: @music2myear I am using a sharktap with the ethernet cable normally plugged into the Wago, so wireshark is technically outside the Wago ethernet controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question, due to almost total ignorance about computer networking: do the packets that are on the network that are not being sent to or received by the ip address of a device still contribute to the device's total bit rate?

It's not the device's total bit rate but the Ethernet link's – 10 Mbps is one of the standard data rates for an Ethernet connection (10BASE-T) – so any packet that crosses the Ethernet cable will contribute to the "total bit rate", and it physically cannot send more than 10 Mbps (in one direction) when running in this mode.

It's the sender (e.g. Ethernet switch) that makes the decision whether to send something or not; the device cannot refuse to receive a packet once it hits the wire, even if that packet doesn't have the right address. Either it has to receive and discard the whole packet (meaning that all such misdirected packets contribute), or "the network" has to avoid forwarding in towards the device the first place.

On modern networks it's the Ethernet switches that would be responsible for filtering most of the unrelated traffic, based on its destination **MAC** address. They learn which MAC address is behind which switch-port, and in normal situations *only* packets sent to your MAC (plus broadcast packets) should be output through the Ethernet switch-port that you are connected to.

It means that even with Wireshark in promisc mode, you shouldn't be seeing packets meant for other devices' MAC addresses – if your test Wireshark laptop is receiving a ~38 Mbps flood of packets *not meant for it*, then something wrong is going on. (Though I can't really speak for industrial networks, but you should not be seeing that on any ordinary Ethernet LAN.)

Sometimes this filtering doesn't quite work; it relies on the switches *learning* the MAC-to-port mapping based on packets that each device sends. If a device stays completely quiet then switches won't have the opportunity to learn where its MAC address is, so every packet meant for that device will be broadcast through all ports instead. If the network has 100 devices receiving commands but never speaking, it's certainly possible that those packets will be flooded. On the other hand, if you're seeing bidirectional communication, that's definitely not right.

The second stage of filtering, within the Ethernet controller, is what "promisc mode" in Wireshark refers to (re music2myear's comments) – the controller would discard *received* packets if they don't have the right MAC address (and Wireshark temporarily turns this off to do its job) – before passing them "up" for further processing. This used to be a necessity on shared-medium networks. But on switched networks, promisc mode cannot "pull" packets that the switch isn't supposed to be sending you, so I doubt that it would be the problem.

(Checking for IP address is another stage *after* that; only after switches forward the packet towards your port, and the controller accepts it as having the correct destination MAC, then the destination IP address comes into play.)